# For loop on an object is getting out of control

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm working with a project that has this crazy for loop to expand nodes in a D3.js canvas interactive. Essentially, what I want is to expand all children. So if an object has a child, I want to expand them.

I cut out a chunk of code from this. There's so many for loops it's ridiculous. How can I reduce this to a simple "find all children, preform toggle(); and update();"?

```
$('.expandAll').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    length = root.children.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        toggle(root.children[i]);
        update(root);

        if (root.children[i]['children']) {
            childlength = root.children[i]['children'].length;

            for (var j = 0; j < childlength; j++) {
                toggle(root.children[i]['children'][j]);
                update(root);

                if (root.children[i]['children'][j]['children']) {
                    childlength2 = root.children[i]['children'][j]['children'].length;

                    for (var k = 0; k < childlength2; k++) {
                        toggle(root.children[i]['children'][j]['children'][k]);
                        update(root);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's... it's out of control! Stop the main reactor! ... but really. Why not just build a few functions?

Comment: Recursion! Recursion! Recursion!

Comment: do you know, what a recursive function is?
Do  it recursive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a good case for recursion:

```
$('.expandAll').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    expandAll(root);
});

var expandAll = function (node) {
    toggle(node);
    update(node);

    // edit: if nodes with no children are lacking the children property
    if (!node.children) {
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0, length = node.children.length; i < length; i++) {
        expandAll(node.children[i]);
    }
};
```

I'm not sure what `toggle` and `update` exactly means, but you may be able to perform just a single top-level `update` call after calling `expandAll(root);`.

Comment: This will either cause a stack overflow or a `cannot access 'i' on undefined` exception? It seems leaf nodes do have *no* children array instead of one with length 0.

Comment: @Bergi sounds like a problem with the node objects, not the loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)! If you need to support only three levels, you can introduce a counter variable for that.

```
$('.expandAll').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    expandAll(root, root.children/*, 3*/);
}
function expandAll(root, children/*, lev*/) {
    if (!children/* || lev<=0 */) return;
    var length = children.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         toggle(children[i]);
         update(root);
         expandAll(root, children[i].children/*, lev-1*/);
    }
}
```

Btw, are you sure that you need to call `update` on the `root` after every single `toggle`? It would make more sense to me to call it once in the end when all children are toggled.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but something I've been doing with nested objects:

```
object = {
    children: [], // array of similar objects with children property and update function
    update: function(data){
        // update this item
        this.data = data;

        // update each immediate child
        if (this.children)
            for (var i in this.children)
                this.children[i].update(data);
    }
};

// then you just call update on the first item:
object.update(data);
```

If you follow this pattern, rather than setting up complex loops at the root level, you simply loop through the immediate children and call their update function, which then loops through their children, and goes all the way down.

I'm not a great JS developer, just something I was doing for some nested comments I was working with the other day ;)